# Disappearing Images

Tags: javascript, css

I am still new to Sharepoint and I am trying to upload some files from my staging area to production. Everything work in staging however when I move the files to production, I noticed that there are two images that are displaying on some pages and not others. Does anyone have an idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this issue is related to some permission problem.
A) If it's a picture library, check if your pictures are published.
B) Check if the picture library has the appropriate permissions.